# How to export dynamic track (video) from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, map-service, tracking, video

Is it possible to export a file video with QGIS with a dynamic track from point A to point B?

I need something like a presentation of a race where a dot is moving along the track from the start to the finish

I use QGIS 2.6.1

Comment: I think this can be achieved with the **Time Manager** plugin as there was a [project involving moving points](https://qgis2015.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/qgis-timemanager-and-how-the-qgis-community-helped-me/) as shown in a video from the link.